# Display HTML child element when parent element is display:none

Tags: html, css

Is there any mechanism to display a child element when its parent element is display: none?

The situation is a validation error on a hidden tab. I want to surface the error message, even though the field is hidden.

A really simplified JSFiddle of the situation is here http://jsfiddle.net/vLYnk/

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="hide">
        Two
        <ul>
            <li class="reshow">Re Show Me</li>
            <li>Inner 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {display: none}
.reshow {display: block !important; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

I'm guessing this is impossible as the child would have no context, but just in case???

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No this isn't possible. `display:none` hides the element, and thus any child elements will not be displayed.

**EDIT:**

This might be along the lines of what you want, if you're able to switch from using `display` to `visibility`.

```
.hide {visibility: hidden;}
.reshow {visibility: visible;}
```

Using this method you can hide the contents of the parent element but show the specific `<li>` you want. The only caveat is the parent markup will still take up screen real estate. Just won't be shown to the user. That may or may not break the layout you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLYnk/2/

Comment: @Andiih Ok - I've updated the answer with an alternate solution using `visibility` rather than `display` CSS attribute.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. You could instead move the child element out of its hidden parent and insert it somewhere else in the markup (e.g. via JavaScript).

Comment: that was what I thought...was just hoping I didn't have to go that route.

Answer (score 4):

For specific situations you can use this either:

```
.hidden-container *{display:none;}
.hidden-container .show-again{display:block}
```

That will keep `.hidden-container` displayed, but everything except `.show-again` container will have display property set to `none`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amens/jyKSu/)

EDIT:

note, that it'll reset all display properties in childs of `.hidden-container` if declared after their styles.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is misleading because it only works if you have no nesting for child elements.  It works only for hiding siblings of the element, otherwise it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/jyKSu/1/

Comment: Though I like this answer, I've heard using * in CSS can really slow down a  mobile browser.  I wonder the effects of using it as dependent?

Comment: * is not too slow if you have an exact parent element.

Answer (score 4):

Just add .hide:

```
font-size: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

It will not occupy the space just as display none

Comment: This works great, but only if the element to be hidden is text.

Answer (score 3):

You could instead of using display: none; to hide your element move it out of the viewport via position: relative/absolute; and left: -9999em;
Than give the visible child a position: relative; and left: 9999em;

The downfall of this solution is, that the "reshown" element is out of the element flow if you used position: absolute. (Not occupying the space it needs and not pushing down following elements)
Or that you occupy more space than is actually needed, when using position: relative.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLYnk/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').append($('.reshow').clone(true));
```

Comment: The validation message is generated client side, so I'd need to hook into some event to fire this...already thinking down these lines.