# Filter LIs with text input - nested LIs not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, nested, html-lists

I am trying to filter a UL for specific LIs with a keyup text input. Problem is, the LIs are nested within a tree, and the filter only sees the top most LI and doesn't appear to be filtering correctly. Typing Pennsylvania should show ONLY Pennsylvania, and nothing above it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/412

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' value='[Enter search term followed by Return]' class='allW treeSearch' />
  <ul id="treeview">
    <li data-expanded="true"><span class="icon-location-7 md-moon delBlue treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe6b5;"></span>
    <span class="icon-location-7 md-moon white treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe6b5;"></span>Root
        <ul>
            <li data-expanded="true"><span class="icon-stack-6 md-moon delLtBlue treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe6a0;"></span>
            <span class="icon-stack-6 md-moon white treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe6a0;"></span>Gas Model
              <ul>
                  <li data-expanded="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe md-moon delGreen treeSpace"></span>
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe md-moon white treeSpace"></span>United States
                    <ul>
                        <li data-expanded="true"><span class="icon-pie md-moon delBlue treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe708;"></span>
                        <span class="icon-pie md-moon white treeSpace" data-icon="&#xe708;"></span>Pennsylvania

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.treeSearch').click(function(){
    $(this).val(''); 
});

$('.treeSearch').keyup(function(){

    var searchText = $(this).val();

    $('#treeview ul').each(function(){

        var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
            showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

        $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

    });     
});
```

Comment: So you want US and other lis above it to be hidden when you type *Penn*

Comment: is this what you need http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcYpD/3/

Comment: No, i need only the searched li to show. Not everything above it. "Typing Pennsylvania should show ONLY Pennsylvania, and nothing above it."

Comment: an intermediary result can be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcYpD/4/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, +1 to that idea. I don't see another way to show a child of a hidden parent element.

Comment: When you hide an element, you hide all of it's children.  You can't hide 'United States' and _not_ hide 'Pennsylvania', CSS does not allow that.  In order to solve your problem you will have to create and modify additional markup on the page above and beyond what you have presented here.

Comment: you can use CSS visibility [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956970/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956970/2359055) something like [http://jsfiddle.net/HLWMv/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/HLWMv/1/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, that is a good idea. Post that as a answer also.

Comment: @Sergio what about http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcYpD/6/

Comment: @triplethreat77 checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gcYpD/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you do not want to change the html you can change .toggle() for .css("visibility")

```
$('.treeSearch').click(function(){
    $(this).val(''); 
});
$('.treeSearch').keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val();
$('#treeview li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){
var currentLiText = $(this).text();
    if(currentLiText.replace(/\s+/g, '')!=""){
        if(currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1){
            $(this).parent("li").css({"visibility": "visible"});
        }
        else{
         $(this).parent("li").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        }
    }
});     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HLWMv/1/
this will only show the actual "li"
to remove the `if(currentLiText.replace(/\s+/g, '')!=""){` part you need to remove the extra spaces and new lines in your html
UPDATE
case insensitive

```
$('.treeSearch').click(function(){
$(this).val(''); 
});
$('.treeSearch').keyup(function(){

var searchText = $(this).val();

$('#treeview li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function(){

    var currentLiText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        if(currentLiText.indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            $(this).parent("li").css({"visibility": "visible"});
        }
        else{
         $(this).parent("li").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        }
});     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HLWMv/2/
I removed the spaces in the HTML

Comment: Can this be not case sensitive?

Comment: Unfortunately, this perfect solution will not work with the kendo ui widget I am using. It seems you cannot show/hide the li's. http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/412/

Comment: to work with kendo you need to change the id of #treeview like this [http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/413/](http://jsfiddle.net/CDAVZ/413/)

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, can this be case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This make extensive dom manipulations.... please beware about the cost associated with it**

From what I can understand, you need to make dom structure changes to achieve this

```
$('.treeSearch').click(function () {
    $(this).val('');
});

RegExp.quote = function (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

$('#treeview li').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.contents().map(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) != '' ? $.trim($(this).text()) : undefined;
    }).get().join(' ');

    $this.data('parent', $this.parent()).data('text', text);
})


$('.treeSearch').keyup(function () {

    var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.quote(this.value), 'i');

    var $selected = $('#treeview li').removeClass('selected').hide().filter(function () {
        return regex.test($(this).data('text'));
    }).addClass('selected').show();

    $selected.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            $ul = $this.data('parent');

        var $li = $this;
        while ($ul.is(':not(#treeview)') && !$ul.parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $li = $ul.parent();
            $ul = $li.parent();
        }
        $this.appendTo($ul)
    })

});
```

Comment: You missed *" and nothing above it."*