# Only print elements with a certain class in nested divs

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It is possible to hide everything on a page and only show elements with a certain class. Using the following css, only elements with the `print-me` clas should be printed.

```
@media print {
  .print-me, .print-me * {
    display: inline;
  }
  body * {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But this only works when `print-me` elements are direct children of `body`. When there is another element wrapped around the classes, as in the following html, nothing is displayed when printing.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>  
      <div class="print-me">
        <p>This text should be printed, but isn't.</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This text isn't printed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/MiniXC/pen/gpqWPQ); [Debug View](http://s.codepen.io/MiniXC/debug/gpqWPQ?)

Comment: This occurs because the direct child element of body, has a selector that sets it to display: none;. It does not matter that the child of that element then has a display: inline, it will always be hidden because of it's parent.

Comment: @Shane But is there a way to display an element even when its parent has ``display`` set to ``none``?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such option to do this with `display: none;` I did however find this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12956970/3270185 that tries to solve it with the `visibility` property. Would this be an option for you?

Comment: @Shane I'll try using visibility, but does it remove elements from the document flow?

Comment: There is no selector that allows selection of parent objects, and traversing through the DOM (with perhaps Javascript) would not be performance friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, try it with the following css:

```
@media print {
  .print-me, .print-me * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

This seems to do what you're expecting.

Comment: Be sure that if you do this that you use the `aria-hidden="true"` attribute on the elements that are print only, otherwise you may create accessibility issues.