# Force div inside tab navigation to appear on top of all other page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with templates, so I can only edit so much of the environment. I have a tabbed navigation set up. Within one of the tabs, I have a div that I want to have a fixed position that is outside/on top of everything else on the page.

This isn't the actual code I'm working with, but it's similar enough that I can use it as an example. The "outsidediv" div is placed in the "London" div. But I want to make it so you see outsidediv even if you click into the Paris or Tokyo tabs.

I've tried using z-index and every kind of position property I can think of to get this to work. I cannot move the outsidediv from where it is.

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#outsidediv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 50px;
  background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <div id="outsidediv">This div should appear no matter which tab is selected.</div>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why does it have to be inside the London div?  "I have a div that I want to have a fixed position that is outside/on top of everything else on the page."  Why not do just that? Place it outside/on top of everything else on the page. Leave its CSS exactly the same.

Comment: Because of the templating system I am using, it has to be within a div.

Comment: Unfortunately "display: none" hides all children, nothing you can do against that with css, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956937/display-html-child-element-when-parent-element-is-displaynone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is any other way to do this other than to move the `div` so that it's outside of the tab, and give it a very high `z-index` because once you hide a tab with `display:none` the entire tab (and its descendants) won't be rendered.

**If you can't modify the HTML template structure, you could use JavaScript to move it with this one line:**

```
document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById("outsidediv"));
```

I've also modified/updated your existing JavaScript code so that [you aren't using `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) or [using inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), which makes the code much more efficient and more in line with modern development methodologies. See the comments in the code for details.

```css
/* Just add this class when you want to hide something 
   and remove when you want to show */
.hidden { display:none; }

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#outsidediv {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:9999;
  top: 80px;
  right: 50px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <!-- Don't use inline HTML event attributes. Do your JavaScript in JavaScript-->
  <button class="tablinks">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent hidden">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <div id="outsidediv">This div should appear no matter which tab is selected.</div>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent hidden">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent hidden">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
// Move the div that should stay on top to just after the tab divs
document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById("outsidediv"));

// Just set your event up at the parent of the buttons
// and use event delegation to leverage event bubbling
document.querySelector(".tab").addEventListener("click", openCity);

function openCity(event) {
  // Never, never, never use `getElementsByClassName()`
  // and instead, use `.querySelectorAll()`. You can 
  // then loop through the resulting collection with
  // `.forEach()`, which makes looping without indexes
  // possible
  
  // Hide all the tab conttent
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent").forEach(function(tab){
    // Avoid inline styles when possible and just apply/remove classes
    tab.classList.add("hidden");
  });
  
  // Remove the active tab
  document.querySelectorAll(".tablinks").forEach(function(tabLink){
    tabLink.classList.remove("active");
  });
  
  // Loop over the content again
  document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent").forEach(function(tab){
    // If the text of the clicked button matches the text of the tab header...
    if(event.target.textContent === tab.querySelector("h3").textContent){
      tab.classList.remove("hidden");      // Unhide the tabcontent
      event.target.classList.add("active"); // Make the tab active
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't move the div from where it is.

Comment: @Robby See my updated answer where I just move the `div` programatically and update your existing code.

Comment: I would love for this to work! However, I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: I do have that appendChild line in an external .js file, if that matters.

Comment: @Robby What that means is that the argument  you are passing to `.appendChild` isn't a valid reference to an element in your document. In my example, I'm passing `document.getElementById("outsidediv")`, which is the node to move (the `div` that should always be visible). Make sure that this line of code is processed AFTER the entire document has been parsed into memory. This is usually done by placing your `script` tags just prior to the CLOSING `body` tag of the HTML file.

Comment: I can confirm that the `script` tags are just prior to the closing body tag.

Comment: @Robby Add this line right before the `.appendChild` line and see what is reported in your Console: `console.log(document.getElementById("outsidediv"))`

Comment: I don't see anything new in the Console using that line. I think I found the problem though. outsidediv doesn't get created on page load. So I think I'm going to have to figure out a way to not call the appendChild script until it exists.

Comment: @Robby Ah, yes, well that would do it. The element must exist before that line can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an additional function to add the `outsidediv`. Before adding the element, first check if it exists on the page and if so remove it, then add it to the current active tab element.

Check below:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  var div = document.getElementById("outsidediv");
  if(div !== null) { // if outsidediv exists on the page, remove it
    div.remove();
  }
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  let cityDiv = document.getElementById(cityName);  // made cityDiv variable
  cityDiv.style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  cityDiv.append( makeOutsideDiv() );  // add the outsidediv to the active element
}

function makeOutsideDiv() {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "This div should appear no matter which tab is selected.";
  div.id = "outsidediv";
  return div;
}
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#outsidediv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 50px;
  background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <div id="outsidediv">This div should appear no matter which tab is selected.</div>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `visibility` instead of `display`, and each inactive tab I am setting `position:fixed` and sending it way above the rendered area of the page (out of sight and out of mind).  Then when the tab is clicked again I'm setting it back to `position:relative` with no offset.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tm1wyax6/1/

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <div id="outsidediv">This div should appear no matter which tab is selected.</div>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    tabcontent[i].style.position = "fixed";
    tabcontent[i].style.top = "-1000px";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.position = "relative";
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.top = "0";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.tabcontent {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

#outsidediv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 50px;
  background: pink;
  visibility: visible;
  }
```